# Redefine \varprojlim and \varinjlim to get more pleasant arrows

Tags: math-mode, macros, unicode-math, kpfonts

I am using `kpfonts-otf` as the math font under LuaLaTeX. With `\footnotesize`, the arrow of `\varprojlim` and `\varinjlim` seems strange:

[image]

I assume that the problem here is that `\varprojlim` and `\varinjlim` are not built-in symbols of `unicode-math`. After consulting the "List of glyphs", I found `\underleftarrow` and `\underrightarrow` supported by `unicode-math`, and then tried to redefine `\varprojlim` and `\varinjlim` using them. What I can achieve so far is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\begin{document}

\footnotesize

\( \varprojlim D \)
\renewcommand*{\varprojlim}{\mathop{\underleftarrow{\lim}}}
\( \varprojlim D \)

\( \varinjlim D \)
\renewcommand*{\varinjlim}{\mathop{\underrightarrow{\lim}}}
\( \varinjlim D \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I don't know how to add some vertical spacing between `\lim` and the arrow as in the original version (I tried to add `\mathstrut`, but this seems to cause extra horizontal spacing and thus make the arrow longer).

Is there some way to improve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a small strut, here the depth is 0.2ex, adjust to suit. The braces around `\lim` are necessary to avoid TeX inserting spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

\newcommand{\limstrut}{\vrule depth0.2ex width 0pt}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\varprojlim}{\mathop{\underleftarrow{{\lim}\limstrut}}}%
  \renewcommand{\varinjlim}{\mathop{\underrightarrow{{\lim}\limstrut}}}%
}
\begin{document}

\( \varprojlim D \)
\( \varinjlim D \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What’s with the weird, slanted look of the arrows heads? (I know this was also in the original question.)

Comment: @Gaussler Font design.